# differences in python 3.5 vs 3.6 when print() unicode charcters?

Tags: unicode, terminal, python-3.6, python-3.5

My python file:

```
print('Amanhã')
```

I am using the integrated terminal in VSCode 1.28.1, on Windows 10 Pro.

When I activate a Python 3.6-based virtual environment then run this script, it executes as expected and I see `Amanhã` in the terminal.

But when I activate a Python 3.5-based virtual environment then run this script, it fails with a UnicodeEncodeError: 
`UnicodeEncodeError: 'charmap' codec can't encode character '\xe3' in position 5: character maps to <undefined>`

If I run `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` in the 3.5-based environment, then execute the script, the Unicode error is gone but the output is not exactly as expected: `Amanh├ú`

How can I see `Amanhã` in the 3.5-based venv?

(I replicated this in the normal Windows terminal (cmd.exe), not inside VSCode -- exact same result.  I also will note that `sys.getdefaultencoding()` returns `utf-8` both before and after the `set PYTHONIOENCODING=utf8` command)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on the incorrect output, your terminal is using `cp437`, which doesn't support the character `ã`.

Pre-Python 3.6, Python encodes Unicode to the encoding of the terminal on Windows.  As of Python 3.6, Python uses Unicode Win32 APIs when writing to the terminal and, as you have found, works much better.

If you must use Python 3.5, check out [win-unicode-console](https://github.com/Drekin/win-unicode-console).

Comment: Wow, thank you. Obviously there are a lot of differences between 2 and 3, and across platforms. But I hadn't seen anything describing the change in behavior between 3.5 and 3.6.